# How keep carriage return from parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am looking on Internet how keep the carriage return from XML data but I could not find the answer, so I'm here :)

The objective is to write in a file the content of a XML data. So, if the value of the node contains some "\r\n" data, the soft need to write them in file in order to create new line, but it doesn't write, even with space:preserve.

Here is my test class:

```
XElement xRootNode = new XElement("DOCS");
XElement xData = null;

//XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Xml;
//XAttribute spacePreserve = new XAttribute(ns+"space", "preserve");
//xRootNode.Add(spacePreserve);

xData = new XElement("DOC");
xData.Add(new XAttribute("FILENAME", "c:\\titi\\prout.txt"));
xData.Add(new XAttribute("MODE", "APPEND"));
xData.Add("Hi my name is Baptiste\r\nI'm a lazy boy");

xRootNode.Add(xData);

bool result = Tools.writeToFile(xRootNode.ToString());
```

And here is my process class:

```
try
{
    XElement xRootNode = XElement.Parse(xmlInputFiles);
    String filename = xRootNode.Element(xNodeDoc).Attribute(xAttributeFilename).Value.ToString();
    Boolean mode = false;
    try
    {
         mode = xRootNode.Element(xNodeDoc).Attribute(xWriteMode).Value.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(xWriteModeAppend);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         mode = false;
    }

    String value = xRootNode.Element(xNodeDoc).Value;
    StreamWriter destFile = new StreamWriter(filename, mode, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);

    destFile.Write(value);
    destFile.Close();

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: you should place such data into <![CDATA[""]]> because XML will try to parse them .

Comment: Its the job of an xml parser to normalize the different line feeds to \n. So this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to preserve cr lf in element or attribute content when saving a `XDocument` or `XElement` you can do that by using certain `XmlWriterSettings`, namely `NewLineHandling` to Entitize:

```
        string fileName = "XmlOuputTest1.xml";

        string attValue = "Line1.\r\nLine2.";
        string elementValue = "Line1.\r\nLine2.\r\nLine3.";

        XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root",
                                      new XAttribute("test", attValue),
                                      elementValue));

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xws))
        {
            doc.Save(xw);
        }

        doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("att value: {0}; element value: {1}.",
                           attValue == doc.Root.Attribute("test").Value,
                           elementValue == doc.Root.Value);
```

In that example the value are preserved in the round trip of saving and loading as the output of the sample is "att value: True; element value: True."

Answer (score 1):

Heres a useful link I found for parsing an Xml string with carraige returns, line feeds in it.

[howto-correctly-parse-using-xelementparse-for-strings-that-contain-newline-character-in](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a5ccf86-d18f-4b37-bc33-4c657eab72da/howto-correctly-parse-using-xelementparse-for-strings-that-contain-newline-character-in)

It may help those who are parsing an Xml string.

For those who can't be bothered to click it says use an XmlTextReader instead

```
   XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));
   XElement items = XElement.Load(xtr);
   foreach (string desc in items.Elements("Item").Select(i => (string)i.Attribute("Description")))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("|{0}|", desc);
   }
```